# Как прибавть к столбцу число и вернуть сумму в SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Как в SQLAlchemy сделать запрос следующего вида:

```sql
SELECT mark + 10 from lesson;
```